# onNotificationOpened and getInitialNotification not getting triggered react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have used **react-native-firebase** in my react native project[android platform] to show the app notification. With this library i am able to show the notification when the app is in the foreground/background/closed state.

According to the react native firebase documentation the **onNotificationOpened** should be triggered when the app is opened by the notification tap. However this is not happening in my case, the **onNotificationOpened** method is never called and **getInitialNotification** method always gets a null value.

I am also using **react-native-splash-screen** library to display the splashscreen.

Here's my code from **App.js** >> **componentDidMount()**

```
 firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
            .then(() => {

                const myAppChannel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('my-channel',
                    'my Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
                    .setDescription('my channel');
                firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(myAppChannel);


                this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {

                    const {title, body} = message.data;
                    const notificationDisplay = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                        .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setBody(body)
                        .setData({
                            key1: 'value1',
                            key2: 'value2',
                        }).setSubtitle('notification')
                        .setSound('default');
                    notificationDisplay
                        .android.setChannelId('my-channel')
                        .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
                        .android.setAutoCancel(true).android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
                        firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notificationDisplay);
                });


                this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
                    //never gets called
                    console.log('onNotificationOpened was triggered on notification taped');

                });

            })
            .catch(error => {
                // User has rejected permissions
                console.log("user rejected");
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

**UPDATE**: Problem was caused by the *react-native-splash-screen* library, I was able to fix this after removing the *react-native-splash-screen library* from the android project. However i am still not sure how i can make this work when using the *react-native-splash-screen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `intent-filter` to `MainActivity` and `click-action` to notification JSON did the trick for me.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Notification JSON

```
{
"to":"ID",
 "notification" : {
      **"click_action" : ".MainActivity",** 
      "body": "Message Body",
      "title" : "Call Status",
      "sound": "default",
      "badge":"5"
   },
  "data": {
      "type": 1,
      "body": "Message Body",
      "title" : "Call Status"
  }
}
```

My manifest.xml looks like this

```
 <application
      tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the react-native-splash-screen from my project and choosed some other approach for displaying the splash screen. But i will give this a try. I guess the ios should also have the same problem please let me know how did you solve for the ios

Comment: Hello, can you check this question please @Hariks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification

Comment: @SelvesanMalakar Can you suggest an alternative to react-native-splash-screen ?